# ASP Classic - convert base64binary string to byte array

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to convert a base64binary string to a byte array in classic ASP. StrConv() doesn't exist in ASP.

My objective is to take the base64binary string received from a web service call, and write the binary format to a file.

thanks,
-m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When faced with a similar situation some time ago, I used [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742(VS.85).aspx) to convert the data to a byte array before saving it to a file. You will need version 3 or higher.

To do this you would:

- Load the data with MSXML
- Set the node's [`dataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762763(v=VS.85).aspx) property to `bin.base64`
- Read the binary data from the node using the [`nodeTypedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762308(v=VS.85).aspx) property
- To save the file you can use the [ADODB.Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675032(VS.85).aspx) component.

A few links on how the to this are below.

http://ghads.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/vbscript-readwrite-binary-encodedecode-base64/

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/254388

http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_binasp/

Comment: Excellent!  This helped a lot!