# How to display an image returning as string in classic ASP?

Tags: web-services, asp-classic

I have a Web Method returning the image in the form of a string.

I have to display it in the Classic ASP user interface by converting it to jpg or jpeg format.

I am able to do the same thing in ASP.NET by calling the Web Service method and converting it to formbase64 format then storing the returning string value in byte[] i.e.

```
byte[] byteArrayofimage = System.convert.FormBase64String(WebmethodClass.Webmethod(Parameter1,Parameter2));
Response.ContentType ="Image/Jpeg";
Response.BinaryWrite(byteArrayofimage);
```

but not in Classic ASP... Please help to get these lines in Classic ASP.

Comment: I believe you will find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633160/asp-classic-convert-base64binary-string-to-byte-array).

Comment: @ShadowWizard am not able to follow that code could you help me by sort it here with required codes...

Comment: I'll see what I can do but can't promise anything. You really better try something on your own, learn how it works, update your post here with your progress and then others would also be able to help.

Comment: I accept your point, let me try something and will update here for sure Thank you @ShadowWizard

Comment: @ShadowWizard one thing please help me to usderstand this lines of code from [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10676/Class-implementation-for-using-webservices-in-ASP)

Comment: You mean the first block, the usage example? It's pretty straightforward, which of the lines you don't understand?

Comment: You know me right.. i dont know how to and much about classic ASP and stuffs, so if you provide me the information of how to start this from the scrach... where those piece of code should be placed to til the execution of it.. just a highlevel description of it...

Comment: Take all the code below "The class that implement the call to webservice is:" and put as-is, with the "<%" and "%>". Then after this code, have your own code. In your own code, in the part where you need to use the service, put the lines "dim ws" and "set ws = new webservice" then the rest of the lines, changing the URL to the URL of the service you are using etc.

Comment: So we have to put the class implementation and the consuming web service code in same page right?? i.e. first those class implemention code within the tags <%-------%> then our Html code that header body then within the tags <%-------%> need to give the implementatin of web service process..??

Comment: Actually better practice is putting the class in a separate file then linking it in your own file, but having it in one file also works and is less trouble for you.

Comment: Do we need to add any service/ web references to get the web service known to our Classix ASP applicaion as like ASP.Net??

Comment: Give me inforamtion about creating a class and linking it in the application so that we could reuse the class file for different modules... creating and linking is similar like what we used to do in ASP.Net... that is, creating a class file and creating an object for that that and so on??

Comment: The key point is that you need a Base64 decode function.

Comment: @cuixiping yes its working and i have used that decoding function also but i cant able to align it i.e. showing it in a exact place where i want to so i have used one separate file called logo.asp and it has those lines of code to fetch the image blob and in the main page where i really want to show the image- there i have included one image tag <img /> and i tagged that logo.asp page to this image tag's source[src] to display(src="logo.asp"). quite simple and nice way to display image.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have used that way only creating one new page and map that page to the image src to display it in a desired place. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use base64 string as [Data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) to display an image on web page directly, and need not a decode script. for example:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<%=base64String%>">  <!-- classic ASP -->

<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
```