# Converting base64 string to byte array in classic asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, base64

I want to convert base 64 string to byte array in classic asp . The code to decode base 64 string to byte array is as follows :

```
Function Base64Decode(ByVal vCode)
        Dim oXML, oNode
        Set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
        Set oNode = oXML.CreateElement("base64")
        oNode.dataType = "bin.base64"
        oNode.text = vCode
        Base64Decode = oNode.nodeTypedValue
        Set oNode = Nothing
        Set oXML = Nothing
    End Function
```

When I call this function with a small string , then this function works fine . But when I call this function with a large string like as the following :

```
Dim simpleString
 simpleString = "MjY1MDEgICAgICAgICAgIAUNAwMAVBIZPXd3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3cHADk6Ojo6 Ojh3d3d3d3d3dw8KATsAOzo5OTg4d3d3d3d3Dg0IAgEAOzo4Nzc4OHd3d3cODgwIBQQBOjk5 ODY2Nzd3d3cNDQwKCAcDADs6OTc1NjZ3d3cNDQwKCQcEAgA7Ozs4NTY5d3cODQ0KCQcFAgA7 AAA7OTg7d3cPDQwKCQcGAwEAAAAAADs6d3cODAsKCAcGBQIAAAABAgEAd3cODQwJCAcHBgQC AQECAQAAd3cNDQwJCQkIBgQCAQEBADs7d3cPDQ0MCQcFBQQCAAABADs6d3cQDQ0MCQcGBQQC ADs7Ozo4d3cODQsLCgkIBwUDADs5Ojo2d3cLDAwMCwoJCAYDADs6Ojo2d3cMCwwNDQwKCggF AgA7Ozo3d3cNDg4ODg4NCwkHBQI7Ojg3d3cODg4ODg4ODAoIBgM7OTc3d3cODw4NDg4ODg0K BwQ5NzQyd3cODw8QEBAQEA8MCAQ6NTIwd3cODxITFBUUEhIRDQk7NDIwd3cPERYXGBoZFxcX FRMxMjEtd3cRFBkbHB4eHh0dHR8nLS8ud3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d0dcHUk0cmEXfDNP gB4PGR4RGQxpIhFiCUlobhpURScuTmh4gl4iJXSENBxtgDeFcnM/YGt8eW1lOCGGVywAAAAA AAAAAAAMFRweJi4ySFNaWmVtdnx+gomMk5egp6evtLa3urwYGyEtP1JTWVtcXWpzdnh+f3+C hoaOkZqcnaGkpamtAAAAAAAAAAAADAAXAQsBDBYAChcAFhQJCRUIFRcVCRcVBwMDCBMSAAwN DAwLDBcKAAwLCQwBCg0MAAkLDAEBDAAJCQ4JBwAAAAAAAAAAAAMASBIZNXd3d3d3d3d3d3d3 d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3cCAzs1MTAud3d3d3d3d3d3d3c7Ojg0MS8tLC13d3d3d3d3ADs5ODYz MS4tLCl3d3d3d3cCADk3NjUzMS4tKygnd3d3dwUDADg2NTQyLy4sKicld3d3BQUDATo2NDMy MC4sKCUkd3d3BQUDATo3NDIxLy4qJiUmd3d3BgUDADo3NDEuKyooJyYmd3cLCAYFAwA3Mi8s KScnJSQld3cNCQgHBQE0Ly0qKCYlIiIkd3cQDAsKBgAzLSopJiUkJCMld3cQDw4NCToxKign JCIjJCUld3cSEhEQDTorJSUlIyIiJCYld3cWFhUTEh4nJCMjIiIiIyYmd3ccHBwbGiAjIiIi IiIjIiQld3chICAgICAhIiIiIiMkIyMkd3clIyIiIyMjIyQkJCQmJSR3d3cnJiUlJignJycn JygqJyR3d3cpKiopKiwsKywrKywsK3d3d3ctLS0uLjAwMDEwMC8uLXd3d3cxMTIyMjMzNDQ0 MzQ0d3d3d3d3NDQ0NDQ1NTY2NjZ3d3d3d3d3NTQ0NTY3Nzc2Nzd3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3 d3d3d3d3d2RfNzRaWnMgQT8zSYQgfmU6HCopMz1dDR0jCy4eHkUpbIYtcjd0I3RfCXcLdGJY Uz1lFVM7AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATHCAwMzs9PUNKTFBTVFZYXF1mbm5ucHV6fYGJipyg qBg1XGRrbHZ8goWJiouOk5+kpaaougAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAg4BDA4CEBcNAQwOEAsG EAwJFhUIDxEHBhISEREQDw0PERcFAhEHEQUFBREREREPDg4PDg0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAMAPhIZLXd3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3csKikoJiMkKHd3d3d3d3d3dzEtKignJSEh JSR3d3d3d3d3MS8rKCcmJSMiIyMjd3d3d3cxLysoJiQkJSYlJCQkd3d3d3cxLSgmJCMjJCUl JCUkd3d3d3ctKiclJCMjIyMkJSQjd3d3d3cqJyYlJCQkJCQjJCMhd3d3d3cpJiUkJCUlJiUk JSQkd3d3d3coJiUlJSUmJyYlJicnd3d3d3cnJSUlJiYoKSUlJycmd3d3d3cmJSUmJycoKyko Kikmd3d3d3cmJSUmKSkpKSkqKykjd3d3d3cnJiYmKSsqKioqLCggd3d3d3coJycoKSstLy4t MCsmd3d3d3coKCgqKiwtLi8wMSwmd3d3d3cpKisrLC0uLi8wLiR3d3d3d3cqLC0t','Li8vMDEy MSR3d3d3d3ctLS4vMTIyMzQ1NTF3d3d3d3cwMDEyNDQzNDY3OwB3d3d3d3czNTQ1Nzc1NTc5 Awl3d3d3d3c4ODc4Ojo5Nzg7AXd3d3d3d3d3Ojo6OwA7OjsCA3d3d3d3d3d3Ojo6Ozs7AAED d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3dytQSwtATFYPRUVOYzlXYUVOGjYSO1cxQCdFGlRk N2soS0hnHzNGXyQXOh1HOwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAWISY9UVhcZ2dzdXWB hIiWmpuco6amtrm8vjM0RmBkaHh5eoiPkpygqrGytboAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAEBEQDwMQEBAPDg8ODwIPAQ0ODQ0MFwEMAAAQBREQEQQPAxAPDg4MDQ0MDA0AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMALxIZF3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3 d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3 d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3 d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3dzo5NjQz MS93d3d3d3d3d3cCOzo4NjQyMC8vLnd3d3d3dwUDADk3NTMxLy0tLCp3d3d3CAUDADk3NTMw LiwrKih3d3d3CQYDADk3NTIvLSsqKikod3cMCgcEATo2MzAuLCopKSkpd3cNCwkGATg0MS4s KikoKSkpd3cNDAoHATcyLywqKSgoKCkod3cPDgwIATcxLSspKCcnKCkod3cREQ4KAjUvKykn JycoKCkod3cSEhALBTgvKicnJicoKCkod3cVFBMPCjsuKSgnJiYoKSkod3cWFxYUEDsrKCcm JiYoKSkod3cYGRgYFx4mJicmJicoKiknd3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3dytwJUodKBQ0M2Is MURpZSM5Fh8lRzQPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAABgZmt2d3iamqKiqauxZnqOj5aWmaWnuQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADA8XDRcLFA0MBBcLBAMQFw4ICRcQDAcAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMAIxIZFXd3d3d3d3d3d3d3 d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3 d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3 d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3 d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3dwQ5MTMyLnd3d3d3d3d3d3d3AQI3MjIx Li93d3d3d3d3d3cBOzo1MzIwLy0rd3d3d3d3dwQDADg1NDMxLy0rd3d3d3d3dwQCOzc1NDMx MC4sK3d3d3d3dwQBOjg2NDIyMC4sKnd3d3d3CQUCOzk2NDIyMC4tK3d3d3d3CggEADk2MzIy MC8vLCl3d3d3CwkGATg1MjEwMC8uKyh3d3d3DgsIAjk0MjAuLS0sKih3d3d3EQ8KAzgzMC4t KystLix3d3d3FBMPBTcxLi0sKystLit3d3d3GBcUCjcwLSsrLCwrKid3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3 d3d3d3d3d1FLWCNfSB5vc3RWdXcmK2BeIlVBcwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhY255f4KEhZKYnJ+lsba7dYWHiIoAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgwOCwICFxAPDwIQEBYJ Dw8MDg0QAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=="
  Base64Decode(simpleString)
```

Then I am getting this error :

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Why am I getting this error ? How can I remove this error ? Please help me to remove this error .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP Classic - convert base64binary string to byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633160/asp-classic-convert-base64binary-string-to-byte-array)

Comment: You need to enable "detailed" errors in IIS and "Send Errors to the Browser" needs to be `True`, that way you can workout what the error actually is. See [Detailed 500 error message, ASP + IIS 7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2640526/692942).

Comment: Once you've got the detailed error *(by following the above link)* [edit] the question and add it.

Comment: `simpleString` contains `','` so it's not a valid base64 encoded string. try to fix this first.

Answer (score 1):

Use the method **decodeBase64** from this article [here](https://ghads.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/vbscript-readwrite-binary-encodedecode-base64/).

```
private function decodeBase64(base64)
  dim DM, EL
  Set DM = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
  ' Create temporary node with Base64 data type
  Set EL = DM.createElement("tmp")
  EL.DataType = "bin.base64"
  ' Set encoded String, get bytes
  EL.Text = base64
  decodeBase64 = EL.NodeTypedValue
end function

'e.g.
decodeBase64(your_base64_string)
```

Answer (score -4):

Please try the code below. It may help you convert base64string to byte array.

```
byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(simpleString);
```

Comment: I am trying to convert base64 string to byte array in classic asp . The code given by you is in asp.net or in c# .

Comment: @RajeshKumarSwain you are correct but this question is not about c# *(note the tags on the question)*.