# how to pass byte array to stored procedure from classic asp

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I have a stored procedure having the following syntax :

```
PROCEDURE INSERT_ENROLL_DATA (pCustNo   IN VARCHAR2,
                                 pData1    IN CLOB,
                                 pData2    IN CLOB,
                                 pLength   IN NUMBER,
                                 pSerial   IN NUMBER,
                                 pUser     IN VARCHAR2,
                                 pFingerData IN BLOB)
   IS
      vFingerData   CLOB := pData1 || pData2;
      vErrorDesc    VARCHAR2 (1024);
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO BIOTPL.FP_BIOMETRIC_DATA (CUST_NO,
                                            SERIAL_NO,
                                            BIO_DATA,
                                            DATA_LENGTH,
                                            CREATE_BY,
                                            CREATE_DATE,
                                             BIODATA2)
           VALUES (pCustNo,
                   pSerial,
                   vFingerData,
                   pLength,
                   pUser,
                   SYSDATE,
                     pFingerData);
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         vErrorDesc := SQLERRM;

         INSERT_ENROLL_LOG (pCustNo      => pCustNo,
                            pSerial      => pSerial,
                            pProcess     => 'INSERT FINGER BINARY DATA',
                            pErrorDesc   => vErrorDesc,
                            pUser        => pUser);
   END;
```

I am calling this stored procedure by the following syntax :

```
strSQL = "PKG_BIOMETRIC_PROCESS.INSERT_ENROLL_DATA(3455,'" & strVar1 &  "','" & strVar2& "',"&length_of_data&"," & serial_no &  ",'admin01',null )" 

Set objExec = Conn.Execute(strSQL)
```

This sql successfully insert null data in blob command . But when I try to insert a byte array in the blob data like the following syntax :

```
strSQL = "PKG_BIOMETRIC_PROCESS.INSERT_ENROLL_DATA(3455,'" & strVar1 &  "','" & strVar2& "',"&length_of_data&"," & serial_no &  ",'admin01','" & decodedString& "')" 
                  ' Response.write(strSQL&"<br>")


                    Set objExec = Conn.Execute(strSQL)
```

I am getting this error :

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

How can I pass byte array to blob column from classic asp ? How can I pass byte array data to stored procedure from classic asp ? Please help me .

Comment: You [still need to enable detailed errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158117/converting-base64-string-to-byte-array-in-classic-asp#comment69521028_41158117) before we can be much use, that error is just a generic placeholder sent to the browser when "Send Errors to Browser" is set to `False`.